# Skype close application bug on Ubuntu

Tags: skype, ubuntu-10.10

Closing Skype on Ubuntu does not work.  I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and Skype 2.2.0.35.

When I try to use Skype on subsequent occasions, it says Skype is still running.  I have to kill it the hard way.

Presently I use `ps ax | grep skype` and then I issue `kill -9` on the PIDs.  There are 3 PIDs to be killed.

How can I terminate Skype in such a way that I don't have to issue kills?